# How can I get engine RPM for a vehicle without using the Wheels?

Tags: lua, roblox

Attempting to make a car game in ROBLOX, nowhere else is good for me to ask a question at, so I'm posting here. basically, I want to calculate the engines RPM without using the wheels. is there anything I should do myself to get what I want to achieve? like what should I attempt doing? are there any methods?

As getting the wheels rpm is unrealistic, I wanted to get engine rpm without using the wheels, but I don't know how.

thanks in advance :D

Comment: "nowhere else is good for me to ask"?? what about the Roblox DevForums?  from what I know there are no cars in the Roblox API. you need to implement them using parts and contraints. so you are the guy who determins the RPM. how can you not know it? your question should contain code and more details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any car provided by the game. All I know is an [official tutorial on how to build a basic car](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/building-carkit-1) so I assume that is the way to go.

They use a [CylindricalContraint](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/CylindricalConstraint) of type Motor to drive the wheels. This constraint has a AngularVelocity property. You are in control of that angular velocity.

If you want to stick with combustion engines you won't get around modelling the drive train.

Any way you need to know how a car works if you want to model one. That's nothing we can do for you. If you know how a car works it is obvious how to get the motor RPM. More throttle, more RPM.

This can become arbitrarily complex. Again it is up to you to which level of realism you want to model this.

Maybe start with an electric car. They usually have a fixed transmission ratio and they often don't display RPM as it does not matter to the driver.